# std::move(T&&) and temporary object. Where is the temporary coming from?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm curious about why I can't compile the following code.

It's nonsense code (I know), but I originally faced the problem in some other code using templates with perfect forwarding and such.

I managed to narrow the problem down to `std::move` / `std::forward` / `std::remove_reference`, and I'm curious why it needs a temporary in the first place...

```
#include <utility>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    Foo(Foo&& other) {
        printf("Foo::(Foo&&) %p\n", this);
    }
    Foo() {
        printf("Foo::() %p\n", this);
    }
    ~ Foo() {
        printf("Foo::~Foo() %p\n", this);
    }
};

void test(Foo&& t)
{
    // OK: Works fine and "f1" is is constructed with Foo::Foo(Foo&& other)
    // Foo f1 = std::move(t);

    // ERROR: Here it is trying to  bind a temporary Foo to a non-const lvalue
    // I can't figure out why it needs to create a temporary.
    Foo& f2 = std::move(t);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    test(std::move(foo));
}
```

Compiling with Clang (3.7), it gives me the following error:

```
23 : error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Foo' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'typename std::remove_reference<Foo &>::type' (aka 'Foo')
Foo& f2 = std::move(t);
^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Compilation failed
```

I understand I can't bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference, and there are plenty of questions answering why that is not allowed.

I would expect the code to just carry a reference to `foo` in `main` up to `Foo& f2`, thus not needing a temporary.

Visual Studio accepts the code, but GCC and Clang fail to compile it; although Visual Studio is not as strict of course.

Comment: Try to think about the difference between `int& x = 12;` and what you are trying to do (`Foo& f2 = std::move(t);`). What error is the compiler giving you for each of these statements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well:

```
Foo& f2 = std::move(t);
```

`f2` is a reference, so where are you `move`ing to? You're not actually moving at all.

`std::move` returns an rvalue reference; you cannot assign this to an lvalue reference variable (consider that an rvalue reference can be a reference to a temporary). So, the compiler complains that you are assigning a reference to a temporary (because `std::move` creates what the compiler considers to be a reference to a temporary, that is, an *rvalue reference*).

There's no actual creation of a temporary; it's just that `std::move` returns an rvalue reference, and you are not allowed to assign such to an lvalue reference. (The only possible "temporary" is the one referred to by the `t` parameter, which is declared as an rvalue reference; it so happens that your example passes in something that is *not* a temporary, via `move`, but it could just as easily have passed a reference to an actual temporary).

So in short, the problem is not that it *needs* a temporary, but that you are assigning an rvalue reference (which *potentially* refers to a temporary) to an lvalue-reference variable. The Clang error message is a little misleading, because it implies the existence of a temporary, whereas an rvalue reference might not actually refer to a temporary. GCC produces this instead:

```
test2.cc: In function 'void test(Foo&&)': test2.cc:23:24: error:
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Foo&' from an
rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<Foo&>::type {aka Foo}'
     Foo& f2 = std::move(t);
```

Comment: I know. That's why I said this code is nonsense. This was part of a bigger code base. I simplified to showcase the problem with minimal code. I'm trying to understand why it need the temporary in the first place.

Comment: @RuiFig it doesn't need the temporary - but `move` returns an rvalue reference, which is a "reference to a temporary". `t` is the temporary.

Comment: (well, `t` is a reference to the temporary - the "temporary" which was passed in).

Comment: @davmac `t` is a reference to `foo`, and `foo` is not a temporary

Comment: @M.M please read my answer, and recognize that I used quotes around the word "temporary" in my comment above. I am perfectly aware that `foo` is not really a temporary.

Comment: @Niall 's answer was the first to point me in the right direction, but yours ended up elaborating on a few things that improved further my mental model of the problem. Thank you.

Most notably, I was missing the point that my code does not need a temporary and thus I expected it to work (since it's just passing along a reference), but `std::move(t)` might or might not (from the compiler POV) refer to a temporary, and thus can't be assigned to `Foo& f2`.

Answer (score 9):

> I would expect the code to just carry a reference to `foo` in `main` up to `Foo& f2`, thus not needing a temporary.

It is not as simple as carrying forward the reference. The `std::move` here is a nice way of saying "cast this lvalue such that I can use it as an rvalue". This is in essence why it is not working.

From [the cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move);

> In particular, `std::move` produces an xvalue expression that identifies its argument `t`. It is exactly equivalent to a `static_cast` to an rvalue reference type.

**`Foo& f2` requires an lvalue to bind the reference, you are providing an rvalue reference - hence the error.**

There are no temporaries being created, in this regard the error message is misleading. You are casting references around to allow for [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) conversions. Once these conversions are done, the move can be executed, via the appropriate move constructor or assignment operator.

---

As a side note: VS probably allows this because it has a non-standard extension that allows rvalues to bind to non-const lvalue references (but it will warn you of this with a higher warning level `/W4`).

Comment: See this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/3747990) for more info on the value categories.

Comment: You got me on the right path to improve my mental model of value categories. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are no temporaries in your code.

`Foo& f2 = std::move(t);` fails because an lvalue reference cannot bind to an xvalue.

To fix this you could write `Foo& f2 = t;`.

The clang error message is bogus, perhaps they use the same error message for all attempts to bind non-const lvalue reference to rvalue (an xvalue is an rvalue) and didn't bother to make a different one for this case because it is relatively rare.

Comment: RuiFig is talking about temporaries because of the diagnostic message from clang. `error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Foo' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'typename std::remove_reference<Foo &>::type' (aka 'Foo')`

Comment: Indeed. I have no temporaries that I can see. But the error clearly mentions a temporary. The answer given by Niall seems the best so far. I need to brainstorm a bit and get my head around it.

Answer (score -1):

When you move an object you need to move it to a real location. In the case of `f1` you have created an instance of the class foo and are moving `t` to there. In the case of `f2` you have not specified a location to move `t` into, so implicitly you are telling the compiler to move `t` to some temporary location and then return a reference to that location. This is not allowed by the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

`rvalue` is basically a temporary object returned by some expression. It is destroyed right after being used. Taking reference/pointer to deleted object makes no sense, so it is prohibited in c++